# ImportError: No module named appengine.api in Unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I have the following python file.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/google_appengine')
sys.path.insert(1, '/Users/vinay/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/')
sys.path.insert(1, '/Users/vinay/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')

from google.appengine.api import users
```

This is a unit test python file.

However, when I run the unit test I get the following error

```
/Users/vinay/App-Engine/xxxx/x/env/bin/python xxx/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py /Users/vinay/App-Engine/xxxx/x/tests/test_oauth2callback.py::TestOauth2callback true
Testing started at 10:12 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 129, in <module>
    module = loadSource(a[0])
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 43, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/xxxx/x/tests/test_oauth2callback.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import users
ImportError: No module named appengine.api

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Use Nose and [NoseGAE](http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/) to do unit tests instead of mucking with your path.

Comment: I am using virtualenv and I believe its giving issues with nosegae

Comment: Vinay, did you manage to sort this issue out?